# Section without a chapter number, in a chaptered document

Tags: chapters

I am using chapters.  I want to include one section (a page or two) that does not have a chapter number, and that does not increment the chapter counter.  I've tried `include`ing it, without using `chapter`, and the section didn't show up at all.  How can I include a chapter-less section in a chaptered document?

Comment: Most likely your section was on the next page, since `\include` uses a `\clearpage` 'inevitably', so the content of your external file was shifted the next page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example, use `\counterwithout{section}{chapter}` to remove chapter counter output in front of the section number (this does remove the section counter also from the reset list!)

Later on, it's possible to use `\counterwithin{section}{chapter}` to restore the usual setup.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}

\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\section{Has no chapter number}
\section{Other section}


\counterwithin{section}{chapter}
\chapter{Second}

\section{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Here's a package-less approach, just using a redefinition of `\thesection`, but storing the original version before with `\let\latexthesection\thesection`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\let\latexthesection\thesection



\begin{document}
\chapter{First}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\section{Has no chapter number}
\section{Other section}


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\latexthesection}
\chapter{Second}

\section{Foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** with `Interlude` headings

```
\documentclass{book}

\let\latexthesection\thesection

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\markboth{Interlude}{Interlude}
\section{Has no chapter number}
\section{Other section}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\latexthesection}
\chapter{Second}

\section{Foo}

\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works, thanks!  How can I add a chapter-like header to that un-chaptered section?  I'd like it to look like the rest of the "Chapter x" headings in the document, but saying "interlude" or something like that.

Comment: @horsehair: That's another question ;-)

Comment: @horsehair: See the update