# Changing the format of "section" and "equation" counters in document class "book"

Tags: numbering

I am using document class 'book'. I am using the following code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Def{i}nition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Quadratic Equation}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{definition}
\quad An equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0,\ a\neq 0,\ a,\ b,\ c \in     \mathbb{R}$ is a called \textbf{quadratic equation}. The values of $x$ which satisfies it, is called its \textbf{roots}.
\end{definition}
\begin{proposition}
\quad Roots of the quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c = 0,\ (a\neq 0,\ a,\ b,\ c \in \mathbb{R}$) are given by\\
\begin{align}
    x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
\end{align}
\end{proposition}
\end{document}
```

I want section numbering '1' instead of '1.1' also the equation number is '1' instead of '1.1'. And the numbering definition and propositions should be 1.1 and 1.2.

I tried much to get this effect I could not do. Please help me.

[image: Typeset]

Comment: Related: [Section without a chapter number, in a chaptered document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304600/134144) and [How to leave out chapter numbers in section numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44826/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your TeX distribution is reasonably up to date, you may achieve your formatting objectives by adding the instructions

```
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
```

in the preamble. If your TeX distribution is somewhat out of date, you'll have to load the `chngcntr` package before executing the two preceding instructions.

Some additional comments:

- No need to insert an explicit line break, `\\`, before the start of the `align` environment. In fact, I'd go further and say that it's poor practice to insert `\\` at that location.
- Since the displayed equation in the proposition consists of a single line, you should replace the `align` environment with an `equation` environment.
- Instead of writing a single inline equation, `$ax^2 + bx + c = 0,\ a\neq 0,\ a,\ b,\ c \in \mathbb{R}$`, I'd write three [3!] separate inline equations: `$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, $a\neq 0$, $a,\ b,\ c \in \mathbb{R}$. If nothing else, have three short equations rather than one long one will ease TeX's job of finding suitable line breaks.

  Similarly, I would replace `$ax^2 + bx + c = 0,\ (a\neq 0,\ a,\ b,\ c \in \mathbb{R}$)` with `$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, ($a\neq 0$, $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$)`.
- I would assume that the purpose of `{i}` in `\newtheorem{definition}{Def{i}nition}[section]` is to break up the `fi` ligature. If that is the case, do be aware that using `{}` to break up ligatures works under pdfLaTeX but doesn't work under XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Better to write `\newtheorem{definition}{Def\kern0ptinition}[section]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Def\kern0ptinition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}

\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Quadratic Equation}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{definition}
An equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, $a\neq 0$, $a, b, c \in\mathbb{R}$ is a 
called a \textbf{quadratic equation}. The values of $x$ which satisfies 
it are called its \textbf{roots}.
\end{definition}
\begin{proposition}
The roots of the quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, ($a\neq 0$, 
$a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$) are given by
\begin{equation}
    x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \,.
\end{equation}
\end{proposition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will not `\counterwithout` result in a continuous numbering throughout the book?

Comment: Worked, thanks. I just want  to ask one more thing, I want to use colon after the word 'definition 1.1' and similarly after 'proposition 1.2' instead of dot. How can I achieve this effect ?

Comment: @Bernard - The OP said nothing about restarting the equation numbering when a new chapter starts. I therefore assumed that he/she wants to have the equations numbered consecutively (continuously?) throughout the book.

Comment: @Mico yes, I want restarting the equation numbering when a new chapter starts.

Comment: @prashantsharma - So, basically, you want equations numbered `(1)`, `(2)`, `(3)`, etc in Chapter 1 as well as in Chapters 2, 3, etc?

Comment: @prashantsharma - To reset the counters `equation` and `section` at the start of each chapter, add the instructions `\makeatletter \@addtoreset{equation}{chapter} \@addtoreset{section}{chapter} \makeatother` *after* running the two `counterwithout` instructions.

Comment: @prashantsharma  - Please post a new query for your question `I want to use colon after the word 'definition 1.1' and similarly after 'proposition 1.2' instead of dot. How can I achieve this effect ?`